# Lazy property initialization not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, lazy-initialization

I'm having trouble initializing properties within a `class` using the method described in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization#implementing-a-lazy-initialized-property).

Sample:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private Lazy<string> _lazyString;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _lazyString = new Lazy<string>(() => "hello world");
    }

    public string MyString => _lazyString.Value;
}
```

When I debug I can see that `_lazyString` has its boolean `IsCreated` set to `true` before I've even accessed the `MyString` property. Has something changed in the recent **c#** iterations?

My target framework is **netcoreapp3.1**

Comment: How do you debug your code? By looking with a debugger on a property you will trigger the lazy operation.

Comment: @Progman Dangit you beat me to it by just a couple seconds! The real test here is to either use a class that has some measurable activity when it's instantiated, like outputting something to the console, or to check the `IsCreated` property in code without looking at the property it's being used in.

Comment: The thing is: when I do not provide a property to access the value of the lazy field, the field remains uninitialized! So it feels as though the compiler is optimizing the property

Comment: I am using VS19. Nothing fancy

Comment: You can use `Lazy.IsValueCreated` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.isvaluecreated?view=netcore-3.1#System_Lazy_1_IsValueCreated) to check if the value for the `Lazy` object has been created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works as expected.

The problem with testing this with the debugger, as pointed out by @Progman, is that by hovering the value you trigger the lazy operation.

To really test the laziness in this case you can use the Lazy.IsValueCreated property.

You can see with the following code

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    Console.WriteLine($"MyString not yet called.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Is value created? {c.IsValueCreated}");
    var s = c.MyString;
    Console.WriteLine($"MyString called.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Is value created? {c.IsValueCreated}");
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Lazy<string> _lazyString;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _lazyString = new Lazy<string>(() => "hello world");
    }

    public string MyString => _lazyString.Value;

    public bool IsValueCreated => _lazyString.IsValueCreated;

}
```

Output:

```
MyString not yet called. 
Is value created? False 
MyString called. 
Is value created? True
```

Comment: Tried in my own VS. So it really is the debugger "fake" initializing the value.

Comment: Pausing execution on the second console printout shows `IsValueCreated` with a value of false but `c._lazyString.IsValueCreated` with a value of true